# 'm3.xlarge' is not supported in AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to AWS, trying to run an AWS DATA Pipeline by loading data from DynamoDB to S3. But i am getting below error. Please help

Unable to create resource for @EmrClusterForBackup_2020-05-01T14:18:47 due to: Instance type 'm3.xlarge' is not supported. (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 3bd57023-95e4-4d0a-a810-e7ba9cdc3712)

Comment: m3 instance types are deprecated on EMR, which might be what is causing the issue. Have you tried using `m4.xlarge` or `m5.xlarge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to use latest generation instances. They are technologically more advanced and some times even cheaper.

So there is no reason to start on older generations.. They are there only for people who are already having infrastructure on those machines.. so to provide backward compatibility.

Comment: Almost always cheaper for equivalent specs of previous generations

Comment: Thanks All!!. It is still throwing same error(saying m3.xlarge) even after change it to m4.xlarge. Below the portion of definition. {
      "name": "EmrClusterForBackup",
      "coreInstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
      "coreInstanceCount": "1",
      "masterInstanceType": "m4.xlarge",
      "releaseLabel": "emr-5.23.0",
      "id": "EmrClusterForBackup",
      "region": "#{myDDBRegion}",
      "type": "EmrCluster"
    },

Comment: pls try m5 .. that is latest generation.. if still it does not work ; i will try to replicate problem on my end .. also which region are u using ?

Comment: Thanks Deepak for quick reply. I am getting same error(m3) even after changing it to m5.  I am trying to load data from DynamoDB(Mumbai region) to S3... Data Pipeline is in us-east-1

Comment: Seems like Pipleline was taking Mumabai region as per #{myDDBRegion}. I have changed it to us-east-1 in the pipeline GUI. The current status is WAITING_ON_DEPENDENCIES  for some time... not sure the reason

Comment: I think it is due to this error :Requested resource not found: Table: MyDynamoDBTable not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 74MTIJLJEKC2N68P40B0T1OMMFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG) .  But i can see my DynamoDB table exist in the Mumbai region (Active state) do you know the reason?

Comment: so problem is not about instance type any more.. It is more to do with other configurations. not sure of exact problem now. try to create this table in other region also.. and if it works . u will know that it is taking another region

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem when I have dynamoDB table and s3 bucket created in us-east-2 region and pipeline in us-east-1 as I was not allowed to create pipeline in us-east-2 region.

But, once I created dynamoDB table and s3 bucket created in us-east-1 region and then pipeline also in the same region, it worked well even with m3.xlarge instance type.

Comment: Good to know. So as data pipeline only supports about 5 regions... if you want to backup a db in a different region, you first need to backup and restore your database by some other means and then you can backup your database. yeah thanks aws..

Comment: See my answer below. You can have the DynamoDB in a different region from the Data Pipeline you have to edit the pipeline and set the region to the location of your DynamoDB table

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you. AWS will force you to use m3 if you use DynamoDBDataNode or resizeClusterBeforeRunning

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-override-instance-type/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error but just changing from `m3.xlarge` to `m4.xlarge` didn't solve the problem. The DynamoDB table I was trying to export was in `eu-west-2` but at the time of writing Data Pipeline is not available in `eu-west-2`. I found I had to edit the pipeline to change the following:

- Instance type from `m3.xlarge` to `m4.xlarge`
- Release Label from `emr-5.23.0` to `emr-5.24.0` not strictly necessary for export but required for import [1]
- Hardcode the region to `eu-west-2`

So the end result was:

[image: editing the pipeline]

[1] From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-prereq.html

> **On-Demand Capacity works only with EMR 5.24.0 or later**
> DynamoDB tables configured for On-Demand Capacity are supported only when using Amazon EMR release version 5.24.0 or later. When you use a template to create a pipeline for DynamoDB, choose Edit in Architect and then choose Resources to configure the Amazon EMR cluster that AWS Data Pipeline provisions. For Release label, choose emr-5.24.0 or later.